# How to get the last day of the month using Google’s Query Language GQL?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gql

The [GQL Reference](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference?hl=en_US&_ga=2.48348646.-1113739084.1452107446) lists DATE and DATETIME as functions - but doesn't list DATEADD, DATEPART, DATEDIFF or other common methods that can be used in ways to determine the last day of the month.

How does one determine the last day of the month in GQL?

Comment: For downvoters - can you explain what your issue with the question might be?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible in Cloud Datastore. You'll need to handle that logic in your application.

In the GQL reference you link to, there is only a DATETIME function, but it's for building datetime literals. You can use it as follows:

`select * from mydata where created_at > DATETIME("2018-01-13T00:00:00.000-05:00")`

The same document also references a *DATE* function, but that's only available in *Python GQL for App Engine*. It also indicates that the arguments for the DATETIME function differ between *GQL* and *Python GQL*. It might be worthwhile re-reading some of that document.

More information regarding Python GQL can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/datastore/gqlreference